# OpenCL: Relationship between size of array and global size of work items

Tags: arrays, opencl

Anyone knows the details of how GPU kernels access, say, a large data array sitting in global memory (and that for some reason we can't just copy to shared memory)? Assuming we have a kernel of the type:

```
kernel void doSomething(global A* s, global float* result)
{
    uint gidx = get_global_id(0);
   // some code here using the global index of the thread gidx...
}
```

My understanding - and correct me if I am wrong - is that each thread accesses a contiguous element `s[gidx]` and performs operations on it. Doesn't this imply there is a direct relationship between the size of the global array A* s and the global size of work items? I am saying this only because I otherwise don't see how each kernel would operate on a different data point of the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at how kernels are started from the host code via [clEnqueueNDRangeKernel](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/2.2/html/OpenCL_API.html#clEnqueueNDRangeKernel):

```
cl_int clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(
    cl_command_queue command_queue,
    cl_kernel kernel,
    cl_uint work_dim,
    const size_t* global_work_offset,
    const size_t* global_work_size,   // number of work-items
    const size_t* local_work_size,
    cl_uint num_events_in_wait_list,
    const cl_event* event_wait_list,
    cl_event* event);
```

The number of work-items is specified there, with some additional parameters for dimensionality, offsets, and explicit sub-division into work-groups. But whatever you specify there will determine how many work-items, i.e. instances of your kernel function are executed, and each one of them will get their own global and local index that you can now use to access the data in any way that makes sense for your application (and does not violate the constraints of OpenCL's programming model).

A very typical pattern is to have a 1-to-1 relationship between an array of output data that you want to generate from some input, and have each work-item compute one element of that in parallel. But you could come up with other patterns as well, e.g. starting less work-items than array elements and have each one compute a range of the array, e.g. to increase the work per work-item for a certain hardware target. Usually the work-item range is somehow linked with the output data range, as all work-items are potentially executed in parallel and thus should usually write to non-overlapping parts memory.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you. To be more precise, my question is by which mechanism is the global/index id of each work item related to the index used to traverse the input data structure, the array A* in my case? If you can point me to some material to read on this, it would help me. thanks anyway for your help!

Comment: That relation is totally up to you and your problem at hand. What you get from OpenCL is the index of your work-item within the range you specified on the `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel()`. If your kernel would have two arguments `global float* input` and `global float* output`, and you just wanted to copy data, you would do `output[get_global_id(0)] = input[get_global_id(0)];` and launch the kernel with a one-dimensional range that has a `global_work_size[0]` (argument is an array) of the array size of input/output (element count) .

Comment: I usually recommend this tutorial for people who get started on OpenCL: https://handsonopencl.github.io/